# HttpListener not listening outside of host computer?

Tags: c#, .net, webserver, httplistener

I can use HttpListener to listen for requests coming from the same computer, but I have not figured out how to make it listen to outside requests.

My prefix is:
"http://192.168.103.82:5000/"

I have also tried:
"http://*:5000/"

I can type my local network IP into the browser and get a response. However if I do the same thing from a different computer on the same network, no such luck.

Is there some extra configuration that I need to do? Is this an OS specific problem? I am running Windows 7 Home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to allow port 5000 through Windows Firewall.

Answer (score 4):

From the command:  `netsh http add urlacl`

> The following commands are available:
>
> Commands in this context: add cacheparam - Adds HTTP service cache
>   parameter add iplisten   - Adds an IP address to the IP listen list.
>   add sslcert    - Adds a SSL server certificate binding for an IP
>   address and port. add timeout    - Adds a global timeout to the
>   service. add urlacl     - Adds an URL reservation entry. PS
>   C:\Users\dwalker> netsh http add urlacl ?
>
> Usage: add urlacl [url=]
>                [ [user=]
>                                  [ [listen=]yes|no [delegate=]yes|no ]
>                  |
>                  [sddl=]
>                ]
>
> Parameters:
>
> ```
> Tag        Value
> url      - The fully qualified URL
> user     - The user or user-group name
> listen   - One of the following values:
>            yes: Allow the user to register URLs. This is the Default value.
>            no: Deny the user from registering URLs
> delegate - One of the following values:
>            yes: Allow the user to delegate URLs
>            no: Deny the user from delegating URLs. This is the default value.
> sddl     - SDDL string that describes the DACL
> ```
>
> Remarks: This command reserves the URL for non-administrator users and
>            accounts. The DACL can be specified by using an NT account name
>            with the listen and delegate parameters or by using an SDDL string.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
>      add urlacl url=http://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user
>      add urlacl url=http://www.contoso.com:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user listen=yes
>      add urlacl url=http://www.contoso.com:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user delegate=no
>      add urlacl url=http://+:80/MyUri sddl=...
> ```

example:  `netsh http add urlacl user=Everyone url="http://192.168.103.82:5000/"`